# Load UIViewController, save UIView as an image, without showing on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that's sole purpose is to generate an image to be saved to the users camera roll.
the problem I am having is that the view is always saved as just a black image. I believe this is due to me not wanting to show the view on the screen.

I simply load the view controller from a storyboard like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ResultsViewController *resultsVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultsViewController"];
```

and attempt to save it like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resultsVC.view.bounds.size, resultsVC.view.opaque, 0.0f);
[resultsVC.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:resultsVC.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *snapshotImageFromMyView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Obviously as the view has never been shown on screen, it has not been setup properly.

Is there a way I can fool it into thinking it has been presented, so the views can be built?

------ EDIT ----

I have changed to use a `UIView` instead of a `UIViewController`. The debugger shows that the view looks ok, but when saving to the camera roll it is just black.

```
ResultsView *resultsView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ResultsView"
                                                         owner:self
                                                       options:nil].firstObject;
[resultsView setupWithResults:results forSize:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
NSLog(@"%@", resultsView);


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resultsView.bounds.size, resultsView.opaque, 0.0f);
[resultsView drawViewHierarchyInRect:resultsView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *snapshotImageFromMyView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Do you need a view controller? I have no issue creating a view and rendering that into an image context all without ever showing the view on screen. Maybe your view controller's view isn't being initialized properly.

Comment: Actually no. That is more so I can visually prepare it in a Storyboard. I guess I could use a `UIView` in a `.xib`. Would the auto layout render without being shown on screen?

Comment: Depending on the iOS version, you can end up with a black image because that's not how you make an image out UIView.  It can be as simple as UIImage *snapshotImageFromMyView = view.snapshot;

Comment: I can’t find any documentation on a `snapshot` method on `UIView`

Comment: Please see edit, but still getting black image saved.